# Finding the Max value through GroupBy throws Sequence contains no elements exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following statement, where I use `GroupBy` to calculate the maximum value, and I check if there are any records beforehand using `Any()` but this query still returns `Sequence contains no elements exception` error. Any ideas?

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(s => s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
                     .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
                     .Select(a => a.Any() ? new { Max = a.Max(d => d.Progress) } : new { Max = 0})
                     .Average(d => d.Max) < averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Just in case it is needed here is the `baseQuery`

```
 IQueryable<Submission> baseQuery = _context.Submissions                 
             .Where(s => s.ReviewRoundId == reviewRoundId);
```

I also tried the following as an alternative:

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(s => s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
                      .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
                      .Select(a => new { Max = (int?) a.Max(d => d.Progress) })
                      .Average(a => a.Max.GetValueOrDefault()) < averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault());
```

But it throws:

> Query source (from LearningActionProgress d in [a]) has already been associated with an expression.

**UPDATE**

The following code worked:

```
 baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(s => s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
                                                      .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
                                                      .Select(a => a.Max(d => d.Progress)).Any() ?
                                                      s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
                                                      .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
                                                      .Select(a => a.Max(d => d.Progress)).Average() > averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault() : false); // Here a can be null or empty
```

I had to put this check `s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates).GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId).Select(a => a.Max(d => d.Progress)).Any()`

But, I see this a bit redundant, how can I include this `check` in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a reasonable default object for using DefaultIfEmpty?

[MSDN: DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty)

```
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(s => s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
                     .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
                     .Select(a => a.Any() ? new { Max = a.Max(d => d.Progress) } : new { Max = 0})
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultItem)
                     .Average(d => d.Max) < averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Can you give an example for `Can you create a reasonable default object` ? It would not work just `DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `.Average(a => a.Max)`. a can be null or empty. You have to check it:

```cs
IEnumerable<Submission> baseQuery = new List<Submission>()
    {
        new Submission()
            {
                LearningActions = new List<LearningAction>()
                    {
                        //new LearningAction() { ProgressUpdates = null }, // will throw nullRef
                        new LearningAction() { ProgressUpdates = new List<ProgressUpdate>() }, // this is your problem
                    },
            }
    };

int? averageProgress = 100;

baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(
    s => s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
         .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
         .Select(a => a.Any() ? new { Max = a.Max(d => d.Progress) } : new { Max = 0 })
         .Average(a => a?.Max) < averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault()); // Here a can be null or empty
         // For Expressions use Any again:
         // .Average(a => a.Any() ? a : 0) < averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault());

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n\n", baseQuery));
```

If you want to use this code you could shorten it a little bit. You don't need the anonymous class:

```cs
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(
    s => s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
         .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
         .Select(a => a?.Max(d => d.Progress)) // select the "int?"
         .Average() < averageProgress.GetValueOrDefault()); // Average can be performed on the resulting IEnumerable<int?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but `a?` gives me `...maynot contain null propagating operator`

Comment: It's a null check. If you're working in expressions use `a.Any() ? a : 0` for example

Comment: Gives me the error. You check the update in the OP. But, somehow  with `s.LearningActions.SelectMany(la => la.ProgressUpdates)
                                                      .GroupBy(d => d.LearningActionId)
                                                      .Select(a => a.Max(d => d.Progress)).Any() ?` it works. I do not understand why `a.Any()` is not working as you suggested...

Comment: "I do not understand why a.Any() is not working as you suggested.."
The problem is not that any of the objects used in `Average` does not contain any element. The problem is one level above. There is no element returned by `Select` for executing `Average`.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() helped resolve the error. Thanks for the effort!!!